# How do i tell visual studios to search files with no ext?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to search "abc" but only in extentionless files. How do i tell visual studios (2010) to do that?

Comment: Does this question relate to the IDE in some way or the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL +  F Then  , From **Look In** , Select All Open Documents

Answer (score 0):

```
CTRL SHIFT F + abc..............
```